# Get two result sets in a single call

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-3.0

I'm working on an eCommerce-based website using MongoDb.

In my DBCollection I have two types of documents:

1. Company details Item

   ```
   { doc_type : 'company',
     name : 'Acer',
     type : 'Laptops',
     helpline : '1800-200-000'
   }
   ```
2. Item Details

   ```
   {doc_type : "item",
     item_id : 1001,
     price : 2000,
     discount : 20}
   ```

Now in the product page I need to get data from both documents.

So, first I run

```
db.collection.find({doc_type:'item', item_id : 1001 });
```

to show product data, and then

```
 db.collection.find({doc_type:'company', name: "Acer"});
```

to get company data.

Is there any way to reduce these two calls to one and get data in a single result set?

Comment: is every item of yours related to a company?

Answer (score 0):

If both documents are in the same collection, then yes you can - using the [$or operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

```js
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {doc_type:'item', item_id : 1001},
    {doc_type:'company', name: "Acer"}
  ]
});
```

That will return both documents:

```json
{ doc_type : 'company',
  name : 'Acer',
  type : 'Laptops',
  helpline : '1800-200-000'
}
{ doc_type : "item",
  item_id : 1001,
  price : 2000,
  discount : 20}
}
```

However, if you have two different types of record then it is probably best to store them in different collections.